# Passing Variables References to PHP from Javascript via AJAX

Tags: javascript, php

I have an idea for "using", or "referencing" PHP variables in Javascript.  This would apply to a webpage that will send an email.  A simplified example is shown below.  Note: this is called via AJAX, so it is not the case that I am trying to call a PHP variable from a script that has already been executed.

The javascript will include a "$midSection" string in the body of the email to be sent, and then send the entire body to a PHP script.  The PHP script will store this String, create and assign a value to $fmidSection, and send the body string in an email.  If it works, the resulting email would include the main body sent from the client side, with an inserted "midSection" in the middle of the email (perhaps, depending on the person's name and info stored in a database).

It seems to me that this should work, given my understanding of PHP.  However, it also seems to me that this will open a window for attack similar to an SQL injection (where' perhaps, we can trick the script to assign a different value to $midSection, for example).  Has anyone taken this approach, and if so, can you validate whether this will work, and open up any security holes?

Thank you.

EDIT: The application is for a mailing list, not a contact form.  I have an admin panel which allows me to send emails to the mailing list, and I am thinking that this is a good way to include variables from the PHP in a similar way that I would on the PHP script, by putting the $var in the string itself.  I understand how passing variables from JS to PHP works, I want JS to reference a PHP variable, essentially.  I am not using this for validation purposes, I am using this for an easy way to insert information, rather than doing string parsing manually.  The variable will be created and stored server side on a script that I have created.

Also, the JAVASCRIPT will be performing an AJAX call on the PHP script.  Therefore, the Javascript will be executed first.  I'm essentially sending an email template to the PHP, where the PHP will loop through the email list and add information dynamically, such as first name, last name, etc. Instead of doing string processing, I'm thinking of sending "Hello, $firstName $lastName....." essentially, in the hopes that the PHP script will insert the variable information.

Comment: What's wrong with a normal, boring, everyday *contact* form?

Comment: You cant pass references ( *okay server, the variable is stored at 0AB1E, you can look it up there*) you just can pass values. Google ajax or query parameters or... And youll get many good tuorials...

Comment: I agree with @CD001, what would this actually accomplish?

Comment: You're over-complicating this. If you look up any decent tutorial on a PHP contact form you'll see why this is un-necessary. JavaScript shouldn't be used for any validation (unless it's for preliminary UI styling purposes) as it should all be done server side. And there are ways to prevent injection which definitely don't involve using passing by reference. Post your data from the form, sanitize it in PHP. If you're storing it in a database use something like PDO where you separate the query and data with binding.

Comment: The application is for a mailing list, not a contact form.  I have an admin panel which allows me to send emails to the mailing list, and I am thinking that this is a good way to include variables from the PHP in a similar way that I would on the PHP script, by putting the $var in the string itself.  I understand how passing variables from JS to PHP works, I want JS to reference a PHP variable, essentially.  I am not using this for validation purposes.  (Now that the purpose is clearer, I would like to ask the person who downvoted the question to remove the downvote).

Comment: So why not just make a normal ajax request where you pass the data to PHP via an ajax call? Why do you need to pass a reference rather than the data itself (given that, presumably, you'll just be referring to the data anyway)? There is already an established way to do all of this and you really don't need to use references - there is no advantage of doing that, and potentially more complication than anything else.

Comment: Because I am sending an email template, in effect, where the email, first name, last name, and other info will be populated by the PHP script at each iteration of the email list.  I am looking into this method because I have created an "email preview" on the client side, and would like to put all of the template code there, instead of there AND on the PHP side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the comments above I can see what you're trying to do, but it won't work.

Consider the following code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'ajax.php',
        data: {'name' : 'andy'},
        method: "POST", 
    }).done(function (data) {
        console.log(data);
    });
});
```

This is `ajax.php`:

```
<?php
echo $_POST['name'];
?>
```

All you're doing in the javascript is making a POST request to `ajax.php`. It's able to give you the output "andy" in your console because you're passing this data string - not a reference to anything. So far, so simple.

Now imagine if you change `data:` in the jquery to the following:

```
data: {'name' : '$var'}
```

In your console you would get a string "$var".

Even if you had this in `ajax.php`:

```
<?php
$var = 'foo';
echo $_POST['name'];
?>
```

You will never get the output "foo".

This is because PHP and javascript are completely separate. So if you pass `$var`, it's just going to treat it as a string. There's no way of asking javascript to mean a PHP variable or some reference. You have to pass the data itself.

In the case of your application, what you'd typically do is pass something in the ajax request that PHP can refer to (like the primary key ID for a particular record). PHP would then generate all of the required content and send it back to the browser. If you need to do things with a template, `str_replace` is your friend.

Comment: Ok, that answers the question.  Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

> I want JS to reference a PHP variable

Impossible.

They are different programs running on different computers. By the time the JS starts running, the PHP program will have finished and its variables will no longer exist.

The closest you could come would be to store the data somewhere (e.g. a database) with an identifier. Then send that identifier to JS. Then, if you want to get the data in JS, use Ajax to request it.

Comment: The javascript will be performing an AJAX call on the PHP script.  Therefore, the javascript will create the string first, because the PHP script hasn't even been called yet.  I have edited the question to include this information.

Comment: But you can pass data in your ajax call to PHP. So why not do that? It's like you're trying to pass a reference to the data... Why not just pass the data itself?

Comment: So the JS runs. It calls the PHP. The JavaScript waits for a response. The PHP script finishes. It's variables are destroyed. The output is sent to the browser. The JS gets the response and does stuff with it. It can't reference the variables because they are memory locations on a different location which have been freed by the ending of the PHP program.

Comment: I'm essentially sending an email template to the PHP, where the PHP will loop through the email list and add information dynamically, such as first name, last name, etc.  Instead of doing string processing, I'm thinking of sending "Hello, $firstName $lastName....." essentially, in the hopes that the PHP script will insert the variable information.

Comment: Don't hope. Write code to replace the placeholders in your template language with data. You don't need references to PHP variables in your JS. You need strings you can replace when the template gets to PHP.

Comment: But none of that changes the ajax request/response cycle. It doesn't matter whether you pass variables by reference or the data itself. You send something (the email template) to PHP, PHP manipulates it, and sends it back, which is then accessible in your ajax callback. So how does passing by reference make any difference?

Comment: The difference would be in simplifying the string parsing on my part.  The PHP would receive the string in the "Hello, $firstName $lastName" type of format, send the emails, and return that the operation was successful.  The alternative would be "Hello <myDataFirstName....", then in the PHP script, do a '$body = str_replace("<myDataFirstName>",$firstName,$body)'.  I was interested in the concept.

Comment: Using `str_replace` and placeholders is fine, and the way to go. That's what everyone does. If you send something like `$firstName` through an ajax call, it's not a variable PHP can reference (it's not `$firstName` in PHP) - it's just a string "$firstName" and means nothing to PHP. And in any case, none of this changes the ajax request/response cycle either. So totally pointless, even if it worked.

Comment: Ok.  So at what point does the parser convert "$var" to its value (when coded in the PHP script)?

Comment: I'll post an answer as I'll need to show some code.

Comment: @BrandonDixon posted an answer, hope that helps explain

Comment: @BrandonDixon — When it parses the PHP source code (or when you `eval` but that would be a **massive** security hole). Incoming data over HTTP is not PHP source code.